# Required Single bean but 2 were found even when referenced in Spring config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, jdbctemplate

springconfig.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />  
        <property name="username" value="hr" />  
        <property name="password" value="hr" />  
    </bean>

    <bean id="prodDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />  
        <property name="username" value="hr" />  
        <property name="password" value="hr" />  
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="prodJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="prodDataSource"></property>  
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

Also my main class is like:

```
@ImportResource("springconfig.xml")
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestingFrameworkrunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(TestingFrameworkrunner.class, args);
        EmployeeDao employeeDao=context.getBean("employeeDao",EmployeeDao.class);
        employeeDao.deleteEmployee(1);
        employeeDao.getAllEmployees().forEach(e->e.display());
        context.close();
    }

}
```

This is the error I get-

```
Field jdbcTemplate in com.NettingTestingFramework.EmployeeDao required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - dataSource: defined in class path resource [springconfig.xml]
    - prodDataSource: defined in class path resource [springconfig.xml]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

In my dao file I have:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate prodJdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setProdJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate prodJdbcTemplate) {
        this.prodJdbcTemplate = prodJdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
        String sql="INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql,new Object[] {e.getId(),e.getName(),e.getDescription(),e.getSalary()});
    }
}
```

Why is this giving this error? I have provided the dataSource for both the jdbcTemplates. Also for now can we just ignore the datasource properties values as they are gonna be different for the two data sources.

So I have used ref in springconfig.xml as shown below and I have autowired both the jdbcTemplates.

The "prodjdbcTemplate" is for connecting to the prod database.

The "jdbcTemplate" is for connecting to performance database.

### Update

When I changed my main class to :

```
package com.NettingTestingFramework;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestingFrameworkrunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml");
        EmployeeDao employeeDao=context.getBean("employeeDao",EmployeeDao.class);
        employeeDao.deleteEmployee(1);
        employeeDao.getAllEmployees().forEach(e->e.display());
        context.close();
    }

}
```

and removed @Component from EmployeeDao class and just created an empty bean in springconfig like:

```
<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.NettingTestingFramework.EmployeeDao">

    </bean>
```

Everything worked fine. But the big question is why did the previous thing not work?
As I want this to be a SpringBootApplication is there some solution so that I can do this as in my previous code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["required a single bean, but 2 were found" - Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162150/required-a-single-bean-but-2-were-found-spring)

Comment: Are datasource and prodDatasource the same db in different environment?

Comment: Hi Xavier, I have tried the solution mentioned in that answer. But that did not help me.

Comment: How so if you remove prodDatabase you won't have the same error anymore.

Comment: See this to externalize your properties https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar

Comment: The answer you mentioned is solving the problem when the guy was using both constructor injection and Autowired

Comment: ok if you use spring boot you should use profile specific to your env like application-dev.yml or application-prod.yml and you will be able at launch to choose the right database.

Comment: Can you point out the mistake in my previous code using SpringBootApplication and the one where I removed SpringBootAplication?

Comment: The main mistake is that you use a xml file to declare your spring beans. Instead of using spring boot to instantiate your beans. You should really take a spring boot course. I will learn a lot and win your time. I consider to have answer the problem. Good luck too you in your learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is cristal clear. You have to use only one datasource between (dataSource and prodDatasource).

Remove one of them in your XML or set one as primary.

It should be the same bean and you should just change url and credentials in the config file of each environment.

Comment: I have different url and password for prod environment and performance environment. How will one datasource do this?

Comment: It the same datasource you have to provide properties specific to your environment. Through building (Maven, Gradle) or externalize the properties file

Comment: My question is can I have two dataSource bean in my springconfig or not?

Comment: Leave the database for now

Comment: Yes you can but you will make your code really complex and you will have to choose at runtime or through config. It's clearly not the way to go

Comment: how is this done if the datasource is defined in an xml bean?

Comment: you could have a properties file specific to the env you want to target